# html scraping for td element using cheerio js and node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I have many html files with the below structure. I need to get the values 'GET' and 'http://localhost:5601/app/sense' from the below. but they are not exact same values in the all the documents, it be post, put or delete. but the html structure is same.

```
<colgroup>
      <col class="col-lg-1">
      <col class="col-lg-7">
   </colgroup>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <code>Method</code>
         </td>
         <td>GET</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>
            <code>URL Path &amp; Params</code>
         </td>
         <td>http://localhost:5601/app/sense</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Any suggestion on how to do this with cheerio ? I am trying to parse through the HTML table searching for the method and URL values in td element but I no luck.

```
glob(__dirname + "/../docs/*/*/*/*/*/*.html", function (er, files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

        fs.readFile(files[i], (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            $ = cheerio.load(data);
            $('tr').each(function () {
                console.log($('td').val());
            });
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to target each TD and get the text, it has no value

```
glob(__dirname + "/../docs/*/*/*/*/*/*.html", function (er, files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

        fs.readFile(files[i], (err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            var $ = cheerio.load(data);

            var method = $('tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(1).text();
            var url    = $('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(1).text();

        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .eq and .find methods to find your values  https://cheerio.js.org/

```
glob(__dirname + "/../docs/*/*/*/*/*/*.html", function (er, files) {
   for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

        fs.readFile(files[i], (err, data) => {
          if (err) throw err;
          $ = cheerio.load(data);
          console.log($('tr').eq(0).find('td').eq(1).text());
          console.log($('tr').eq(1).find('td').eq(1).text());
       });
   }
});
```